# Error in setting line fields in inventory transfer through SS 1.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitescript1.0

I m trying to create an inventory transfer from a suitelet and on setting line fields, system is giving me the error to set at least one item.
ERROR:

```
"code\":\"USER_ERROR\",\"details\":\"You must enter at least one line item for this transaction"
```

my code is as follows:

```
datamap object for lines reflecting as follows:

[{"item":"12482","fromLocation":"17","qtytoadj":"1","amount":null,"remarks":null,"project":"6621","projectTask":null,"matReqId":"8636","itemtype":"InvtPart","islotitem":"F"}]
//creating inventory transfer record
    var createInvTrans = nlapiCreateRecord('inventorytransfer');
    //Body fields
    createInvTrans.setFieldValue('subsidiary', subsidVal);
    createInvTrans.setFieldValue('location', 17);
    createInvTrans.setFieldValue('transferlocation', 10);
    createInvTrans.setFieldValue('custbody21', projectFld);
    
    var toData = dataMap[matRecs];
    nlapiLogExecution('debug', 'toData', JSON.stringify(toData))
    nlapiLogExecution('debug', 'toData.length', toData.length)
    
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < toData.length; i2++) {
      createInvTrans.selectNewLineItem('inventory');
      createInvTrans.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory', 'item', toData[i2].item);
      createInvTrans.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory', 'adjustqtyby', toData[i2].qtytoadj);
      createInvTrans.commitLineItem('inventory');
    }
    //sumbitting inv Adj
    var invTrans = nlapiSubmitRecord(createInvTrans, true, true);
```

Can anyone help me is there anything that i m doing wrong? because my Data in datamap is right as required but wherever execution reaches to set lines, the error comes.

Comment: this code is using SS 1.0 functions, are you sure about your question title?

Comment: @Josh just corrected, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong mode. You're using the dynamic mode sublist operations with a non-dynamic record.

You could do initialize the transfer as dynamic :

```
var createInvTrans = nlapiCreateRecord('inventorytransfer', {recordmode: 'dynamic'});
```

or use the server side api for the sublist:

```
for (var i2 = 0; i2 < toData.length; i2++) {
  createInvTrans.setLineItemValue('inventory', 'item', i2 +1, toData[i2].item);
  createInvTrans.setLineItemValue('inventory', 'adjustqtyby', i2+1,  toData[i2].qtytoadj);
}
```